# Distribution of roots of random polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, polynomials

I was playing around with roots of random polynomials with integer coefficients in Mathematica.

Polynomials are generated with

> f[n_] := Sum[RandomInteger[{-50, 50}]*y^k, {k, 0, n}].

I computed roots numericaly and plotted them on the plane

> Y[n_] := Module[{P = f[n]},
> ans = Table[N[y /. Solve[P == 0, y][[j]]], {j, 1, n}]; and]

> ComplexListPlot[Y[100]]

Several runs show that roots tend to distribute around the unit circle (see pictures below). Do you have an explanation for this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: A possible explanation is given [here](http://www.chebfun.org/examples/roots/RandomPolynomials.html).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182412/why-do-roots-of-polynomials-tend-to-have-absolute-value-close-to-1/182637#182637